# cocoapods duplicate symbol _OBJ_METACLASS_$PodsDummy_Pods_xxx

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode6, cocoapods

recently I have update to xCode 6. In my project where I am using cocoapods, after update my pods, I am dealing with an error I can`t resolve and need help. Similar questions in the forums don't resolve my problem and I need other point of view.

The error is:

duplicate symbol _OBJC_METACLASS_$_PodsDummy_Pods_myapp in:

```
/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-cojufufwukcibtcgwjgdbqesleta/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-ibizahelp.a(Pods-myapp-dummy.o)

/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-cojufufwukcibtcgwjgdbqesleta/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-IbizaHelp.a(Pods-myapp-dummy.o)
```

duplicate symbol _OBJC_CLASS_$_PodsDummy_Pods_myapp in:

```
/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/ibizahelp-cojufufwukcibtcgwjgdbqesleta/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-ibizahelp.a(Pods-myapp-dummy.o)

/Users/myuser/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/myapp-cojufufwukcibtcgwjgdbqesleta/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libPods-IbizaHelp.a(Pods-myapp-dummy.o)
```

ld: 2 duplicate symbols for architecture armv7

clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

my Podfile is:

```
#Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '6.0'

source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'

target 'myapp' do
    pod 'MWPhotoBrowser'
    pod 'AFNetworking', '~> 2.0'
    pod 'UIActivityIndicator-for-SDWebImage'
```

end

Please I am stuck

Answer (score 23):

I've had it after target name update, it added pods framework twice - **removing the old framework solved it**.

Project > Target > Linked Frameworks and Libraries

(remove with "-")

Comment: in my case, i have duplicated framework with capital letter and small letter.

Comment: Exact my case, Thanks

Answer (score 0):

go to Finder click ALT and see GO option you will find library and click on application delete derived data.Xcode 6 is entirely new format of data storage.so delete old xcode derived data.

Comment: sorry I can't follow your instructions. Could you be more specific? I have deleted the whole derived data folder inside Library/xCode and the error still remains

Comment: add necessary frameworks Audiotoolbox and Afnetworking and other systemconfiguration

Comment: no one of your answers works... I am really stuck. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

Finally I have found a solution.

It seems that the cocoapods have changed something or my proyect had a problem in the name, not sure at all but my target configuration had an specific configuration set, and cocoapods needs its own.

my configuration set was Pods-myappname-xconfig.release and I the correct was Pods-xconfig.release that was located in the pods folder when install them.

Once I have changed it, the error disappear and I just had to remove from link libraries the old library related to that config.

if anyone has similar issues, I will be glad of help him

Comment: Could you elaborate on what you actually did to solve the error? I don't understand the flow of your answer.